# How to ask a question about blocking annoying auto-play animated adverts on FT.com when using Google Chrome?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

FT.com has recently introduced rather sneaky (my interp!) Bulgari & Mandarin Oriental adverts that auto-play.  I am stumped on how to halt them using Google Chrome.  Sadly, I am a paying customer to FT.com -- a hefty yearly fee!

I am technical (career dev), but I cannot figure out if it is a weird embedded frame with auto-play vid or animated gif.

Is SO the right place to ask about this issue and suggestions on how to stop auto-play?  It seems to post a question about the /current/ FT.com homepage seems hyper-specific and will be stale tomorrow when the auto-play adverts are replaced by something else.

Comment: As a paying customer, do you have access to their customer support?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem but a user one, and one that has many user solutions, from ad blockers to browser configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is for programming questions, so unless your question boils down to something like "I'm trying to write a Chrome plugin that blocks these ads and have this specific problem", it is probably not the right place for such questions.

If you're just trying to block these ads as a user (e.g., installing a plugin, tweaking the browser configuration, etc), [Super User](https://superuser.com/) may just be the place for you.

Comment: [WebApps.se] would be a better choice - Super User is for desktop software.

Comment: Super User is not the place, as per their [on-topic guide](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic): "If you have a question about [x] and it is not about... websites or web services." This would be a question about a website